Starting an app often doesn't bring the window forward
Pretty often if I start an app (which I primarily do from command-space, i.e. Spotlight) the system executes the program, but the window is buried, so I have to then search for it in the switcher. I rarely if ever want something started that way to be buried, what controls that?
This has been true for quite a few versions of macOS, it happened just now on 14.5.

Does the menu bar switch to the started app?

Not sure, right now Console is behaving... as is everything else I've tried.

oops, I edited that, I meant command-space, the search thing

Yah launching from Sherlock should pop the app to the frontmost window. I'm wondering if you have a window management tool running or some such. If you reboot with SHIFT held down (for Intel Macs) or hold the power button for Apple Silicon and select safe mode and see if the behavior is different. Failing that create a new temporary user profile and try it there. That might show a setting got damaged in your primary account.

I'd be very surprised if I had such a tool running, I've never seen one I thought I'd like. I shall, however, take your advice under advisement. I could easily believe a defaults reset might help.

@SteveChambers Sherlock? Not these past 20 years! ;-)

Is "an app" a specific app? If so, what app?  Or is this a problem for all apps?

It's various apps. This is a Heisenbug, so I was hoping it was well known. Guess I'll hope some more.

Ah, yes, Spotlight. I knew Sherlock was wrong, but I wanted to call it that.

Secure Keyboard Entry
A consistent way to cause applications to launch in the background is to enable Secure Keyboard Entry in the Terminal application.

Terminal.app > Terminal (menu) > Secure Keyboard Entry


It's also in iTerm2, in: Iterm2.app > Iterm2 > Secure Keyboard Entry
When this feature is enabled, applications across the whole of macOS no longer launch in the foreground.
This feature should be a System Setting, as it affects all applications, but is oddly hidden within Terminal.

I experience the same problem as @HackSaw but am not using Secure Keyboard Entry. macOS has had annoying focus (and focus-stealing) bugs since Sonoma. See https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sonoma-14-0-annoying-focus-bug-frontmost-app-keeps-losing-focus.2406058/

That's not at all what Terminal's help file says about that setting. From the page: "Secure keyboard entry can prevent other apps on your computer or the network from detecting and recording what you type in Terminal."

@HackSaw absolutely. The setting's behaviour, at least on my systems, is consistent and does not match the documentation. This appears to be a bug either in macOS or in the documentation.

Well, in any case, it's not enabled on my system. I don't use Terminal anyway, preferring iTerm2.

But oh look, iTerm2 has FocusFollowsMouse...

And SecureKeyBoardEntry! Which might have fixed it? Emacs.app was consistently started hidden, starting it from the Finder by d-clicking the icon in Applications raised it correctly, then Spotlight worked correctly. Using 'open -a ...' after that started it hidden. Then I turned off SecureKeyboardEntry, and open worked correctly again. I just now turned it on, and it was hidden. It seems to translate that Spotlight?!?

Thanks, Graham!
